# Android : Google Map Check if Location is inside a tunnel

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I wrote an Android application that uses gps to record location in the file, then I use these locations to draw a path on a map.
When record location and pass through a tunnel I record last position on the entrance, then continue to record at the tunnel exit.
Is there a Google Maps API that I can use to add tunnel location?

If we look at Google map, we can see the tunnels colored in a gray. How can I  know the tunnel bounds?

Comment: I've never heard about such kind of API, also Google Maps APIs don't expose the boundaries of features.